# asp.net file download

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, iis

I'd like to create a asp.net download page. I receive the file from a dataservice as a byte array. The file size can be up to 10gb. So I need to transfer the file "in parts".

Here is my code:

```
Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream"
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", _
              "attachment; filename=" & HttpUtility.UrlEncode(file.Name))

Do
 If Not Response.IsClientConnected Then
    Exit Do
 End If

 result =ReadByte(offset,length) 'read next byte array

 Response.BinaryWrite(fresult.Data)
 Response.Flush()

Loop Until 'all bytes read
```

The code snippet works but I have a big problem. The download already starts before the user confirmed the browser download dialog. If the user waits 5min he has already downloaded the 10gb file without accepting it.

Do you have any solutions?

Thank you

Comment: That's how all downloads work, as far as I know. The server doesn't wait till the confirm button is pressed (how would it tell?). It simply responds to what the browser requested.

Comment: I agree with Oded thats a browser feature and its why sometimes the file is completed before you choose a location. Thats not a confirmation prompt, at that time they are already considered to have confirmed the file download as something they want to do.

Comment: You have to force the download process to push the first chunk of bytes to the browser so that it prompt the confirmation to the user...see code below..it works for me with web response where i wnated to download a file from url, you can update it to make it download the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code need just to updated it to read from file instaed of web response

```
using (WebResponse fileDownloadResponse = fileToDownload.GetResponse())
            {
                using (Stream fileStream = fileDownloadResponse.GetResponseStream())
                {
                    using (StreamReader fileStreamReader = new StreamReader(fileStream))
                    {

                        context.Response.ContentType = "APPLICATION/OCTET-STREAM";



                        context.Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", fileDownloadResponse.ContentLength.ToString());

                        string fileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(url);
                        string fileExtension = Path.GetExtension(fileUriBuilder.Uri.AbsolutePath);
                        context.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename="+fileName+fileExtension);

                        byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];

                        int byteseq = fileStream.Read(buffer, 0, 4096); while (byteseq > 0)
                        {

                            context.Response.OutputStream.Write(buffer, 0, byteseq);
                            context.Response.Flush();
                            byteseq = fileStream.Read(buffer, 0, 4096);

                        }

                    }
                }
            }
```